# Reading File from share point and store it in local file

Tags: sharepoint-online, php

I want to read the file attached to a item in share point and store it into a local file.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible , you can download a file from list item  via CSOM as the following

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{

 var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
 var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
 clientContext.Load(list);
 clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

 var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
 var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
 var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath,(string)listItem.File.Name);
 using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
 {                  
      fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
 }
}
```

Ref : [How to download/upload files from/to SharePoint online using CSOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom)